# Generar nuevo array de otro array interno

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

Soy nuevo en Vuejs y typescript y tengo una interfaz llamada: `StringIdTableType[]` como:

```
export type StringIdTableType = IdTableType<string>

export interface IdTableType<T> {
  id: T
}
```

Entonces mi array es como el siguiente:

```
[
  {
    id: ''
  },
  {
    id: ''
  }
]
```

Ahora tengo un objeto que tiene un array dentro de otro array:

```
MyObject
[{
    ...
  },
  NestedList
  [
    {
      ''
    },
    {
      ''
    },
  ],
]
```

Estoy tratando de mapear una nueva constante de ese array que esta dentro:

```
  const newTableType: StringIdTableType[] = this.myObject.map(x => ({id: x.nestedList}))
```

Pero me devuelve el siguiente error:

> {id: string[];}[] is not assignable to type StringIdTableType[]

Alguna idea de porque esta mandando este error si literalmente estoy tratando de mapear array con array? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!